# TimeSpan addition and subtraction

Tags: c#, addition, timespan

I need to add 2 timespans taken from a textbox formatted like this: mm:ss.fff

For example: 
`00:59,800` + `00:02,300` -
the result should be `01:02.100`, but instead I have `01:02,060`.

I think I have a problem with my conversion below:

```
string Sum1 = "00:" + "00:59,800";
Sum1 = Sum1.Replace(',', '.');
double FSum1 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum1).TotalSeconds;

string Sum2 = "00:" + "00:02,300";
Sum2 = Sum2.Replace(',', '.');
double FSum2 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum2).TotalSeconds;

double SumResult = FSum1 + FSum2;

maskedTextBoxSumResult.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SumResult).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
```

Also, I need to do the same with the subtraction.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the conversions to double? Add directly the two timespans...

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for `TimeSpan.ParseExact`?

```
  string left = "00:59,800";
  string right = "00:02,300";

  var result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(left, @"mm\:ss\,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
               TimeSpan.ParseExact(right, @"mm\:ss\,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  Console.Write(result.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff"));
```

Outcome:

```
  01:02.100
```

Comment: You get my upvote. All the string manipulations perpetuated by other answers here make my eyes bleed.

Comment: why ``\`` needed here ?

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad: ` \ ` is escaping: just skip `:`, `,` and, finally, `.` independent on culture https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(maskedTextBoxSum1.Text);
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse(maskedTextBoxSum2.Text);
TimeSpan t3 = t1.Add(t2);
maskedTextBoxSumResult.Text = t3.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the string to get it to parse.  Use the correct cultural info instead:

```
string Sum1 = "00:" + "00:59,800";
string Sum2 = "00:" + "00:02,300";

var frfr = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");

var FSum1 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum1, frfr);
var FSum2 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum2, frfr);;

var SumResult = FSum1 + FSum2;
SumResult.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff").Dump();
```

Comment: ...but you are modifying the strings, right there on the first two lines.

Comment: first of all, `string Sum1 = "00:" + "00:59,800";` would compile as if it were written `string Sum1 = "00:00:59,800";`.  Also, I assumed that part was just setup to the initial conditions he'd have to work with.  I assumed his actually code started on th enext line, where he modified the string he just defined.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need convert to double to sum the values.

string Sum1 = "00:" + "00:59,800";
 string Sum2 = "00:" + "00:02,300";

TimeSpan sumResult = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum1) +  TimeSpan.Parse(Sum2);

maskedTextBoxSumResult.Text = sumResult.ToString(@"hh:mm:ss.fff");

Answer (score -2):

Many of your conversions are unnecessary. Try this:

```
    static  void Main()
    {
        string Sum1 = "00:" + "00:59,800";
        Sum1 = Sum1.Replace(',', '.');
        var FSum1 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum1);

        string Sum2 = "00:" + "00:02,300";
        Sum2 = Sum2.Replace(',', '.');
        var FSum2 = TimeSpan.Parse(Sum2);

        var SumResult = FSum1 + FSum2;

        var bo  =  SumResult.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
        Console.WriteLine(bo);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```